# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} $ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help finding the the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} $$

I tried to simplify to:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{x\cos x+\sin x} $$

but I don't know where to go from there. I think, at some point, you have to use the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a Taylor-Series expansion? If you know $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}x = 1$, you'll know about the limits of polynomial quotients...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} = \frac{1}{\frac{x}{\sin x}+\frac{\tan x}{\sin x}} \to 1/2
$$

Answer (score 7):

Turn it upside down. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How can I just turn it upside down?

Comment: Take the reciprocal. We get $\frac{x}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}$.

Comment: I can do that? Don't we have take the reciprocal somewhere else to? I'm not understanding how the algebra works out.

Comment: We take the reciprocal, and show easily that it has limit $2$. So the original expression has limit $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ahh, so originally it's something like $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} = L$ and then I can reciprocal and it will make sense since, we also reciprocal the right side to $1\over L$ right?

Comment: That's right. The divide top and bottom by $x$ is a "trick" of greater general applicability, so my opinion is that it would be better to accept one of the answers that uses that.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Divide both numerator and denominator by $x$ and use the fact
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\frac{x}{\sin x} + \frac{1}{cos x}} =1/2$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x+\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}}{1+\frac{\tan x}{x}}=\frac {1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Given that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,
$$
we can calculate that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x \cos x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x} {x} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\cos x} \\
&= 1.
\end{align}
$$

---

Now, rewrite your limit and compute:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}}{1 + \frac{\tan x}{x}} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x \sim x$$
$$\tan x \sim x$$

Hence

$$\frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} \sim \frac{x}{x+x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ratio of the Taylor series:
$\frac{\sin x}{x+\tan x} = \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots}{x + (x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots)}$. Combine the $x$ terms in the denominator, divide out a factor of $x$, and you have
$\frac{1 - \frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots}{2 + \frac{x^2}{3} + \cdots}$. Then you can let $x\rightarrow 0$ to get $\frac12$ because only the constant terms remain in the limit.